# Minimum touch target area requirement for AA conformance

Tags: usability, accessibility, touch-screen

https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/target-size.html

In the above link, it says you need at least 44x44 px to comply with the AAA level. In my understanding, the AA level is a bare minimum to meet. so what would be the AA level requirement of the same? Will it be less than 44px or the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a WCAG **2.1** A or AA guideline regarding target size.  It's only a AAA guideline. So in WCAG 2.1 AA, the target size can be any size you want.

However, in WCAG **2.2**, which is not official yet so this might change, there currently is a new AA guideline, "[2.5.8 Target Size (Minimum)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#target-size-minimum)", requiring a 24x24 px target size.

Comment: Even though it is a draft version, 24px is almost half the size recommended in 2.1. Looks like a letdown for people with motor-related issues. or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess if they are saying AA is 24*24, then that's a stricter requirement since the current 44*44 is AAA

Comment: Exactly, @dougajmcdonald.  This is not a "letdown" because most AAA guidelines are ignored so the target size could be 3x3 currently and pass WCAG.  With 24x24 being made a AA guideline, it'll be required to at least be that size.